# Arc length(calculus)

Tags: calculus

Suppose it is known that the arc length of the curve $y=f(t)$ on the interval $0\le t\le x$ is

$$L(x)= \ln(\sec x + \tan x)$$

for every $x$ on $0\le x\le 1$ .  If the curve $y=f(x)$ passes through the origin, what is $f(x)$?

Kindly provide a reasoning, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$L(x)=\ln(\sec x + \tan x)=\int_0^x \sqrt{1+[f'(u)]^2} \, \mathrm{d} u$$

$$\frac {dL}{dx} = \sec x = \sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}$$

so

$$f'(x) = \sqrt{(\frac {dL}{dx})^2 - 1}$$

And so

$$f(u) = f(0) + \int_0^u \sqrt{(\frac {dL}{dx})^2 - 1} \, \mathrm{d} x$$ i.e.

$$f(u) = 0 + \int_0^u \sqrt{(\sec x)^2 - 1} \, \mathrm{d} x$$

$$f(u) = 0 + \int_0^u \sqrt{\tan^2 x} \, \mathrm{d} x$$

$$f(u) = 0 + \int_0^u \tan x \, \mathrm{d} x$$

$$f(u) = 0 - \ln(\cos(u))$$

So $$\boxed{f(x) = - \ln(\cos(x))}$$

Comment: That helps a lot but Why is f(0) = 0? And from line 3 to 4, when you integrate f ' (x), how and why does it change to f(u)??

Comment: @KaranBhasin $f(0) = 0$ because $f$ goes through the origin. I used $f(u)$ with $u$ as a dummy variable because you can't integrate with respect to$x& and also have $x$ as your upper bound.

Comment: damn, yes. Thanks.

Comment: @TiwaAina, actually you can integrate with $x$ as integration variable and as bound. It is not the same $x$. It is convenient to define a dummy variable $u$ to not be confused, but it is not mandatory.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks